# Publish application for existing customers and otherwise hide

Tags: android, developer-console

it is possible to remove a purchasable applications from the Developer Console? Can customers who bought the application continues to download the application?

I want to prevent from that the application further spreads. But existing customers to continue to download the application.

greetings

Answer (score 0):

Just unpublish the application from the developer console.
The existing users can able to install/reinstall the application if they have already downloaded/purchased once. New users can not find this application in the play store and can't able to download it.
You can also provide update to the current users as well.

Comment: That help me a lot. THX